# items not getting added in cart using react-redux

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, react-native

I want to add items to the cart using redux, its not getting added neither its showing any error.
please help me out. Below is my code

this is cartItem.js

```
export const ADD_TO_CART = 'ADD_TO_CART'
export const REMOVE_FROM_CART = 'REMOVE_FROM_CART'


const initialState = []

const cartItemsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      return [...state, action.payload]
    case REMOVE_FROM_CART:
      return state.filter(cartItem => cartItem.id !== action.payload.id)
  }
  return state
}

export default cartItemsReducer
```

this is store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import cartItemsReducer from './CartItem'

const store = createStore(cartItemsReducer)

export default store
```

this is App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import MainStackNavigator from './src/navigation/AppNavigator'
import { Provider as StoreProvider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './src/redux/Store'

export default function App() {
  
  return (
    <StoreProvider store={store}>
      <MainStackNavigator />
    </StoreProvider>
  )
}
```

this is screen where I am dispatching

```
import  ADD_TO_CART from '../redux/CartItem'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
const addItemToCart = item => dispatch({ type: ADD_TO_CART, payload: item })

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addItemToCart(item)} style={styles.button}>
                                    
<Text style={styles.buttonText}>Add +</Text>
                                
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking the function with an **item** parameter, but where is it coming from?

You must define the parameter and then pass it.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={(item) => addItemToCart(item)} style=
{styles.button}>
```

Comment: still not working